# Javascript: how do I refer to the object which owns the event handler?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with image thumbnails, and each thumbnail has an `onclick` event.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='getInfo();'>
  <img src='album/123.jpg' width='200' height='150' alt='' />
</a>     
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='getInfo();'>
  <img src='album/456.jpg' width='240' height='320' alt='' />
</a>
```

In the event handler `getInfo()` I want to get info of the image I clicked, like the source filename or the height. How can I do this? (I was hoping to use `this`, but that seems to refer to the window, not the `<a>` tag.)
I'm not using jquery (yet), so I would appreciate a pure javascript answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this :

`onclick='getInfo(this);'>`...

then you can get the reference in the method itself

Or you can do this :

`onclick='getInfo(event);'` // IE dont send I think - but chrome do.

and in the function you can get the `Target` .

via event :

```
function getInfo (evt)
{
 evt.target...
}
```

via this :

```
function getInfo (that)
{
   do something with that....
}
```

Comment: @stevenvh ....Hi now I remember [answered](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37184/is-my-device-burnt) .....

Comment: small world, isn't it? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xrzs3/

```
<a href='#'>
  <img src='http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif'
       width='40px' height='40px' />
</a>
```

**onload**

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
   a[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
   var img=e.target;
   var src=img.src;
   alert("image source = "+src);
   }, false);
}
```

Comment: This looked like the most detailed answer, but when I tried to `alert` "src", it returned `undefined`. Thanks for your time, anyway.

Comment: @stevenvh, I have edited the answer with the working code and fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getInfo() { 
        var owner = (window.event.target) ? window.event.target  : window.event.srcElement;
        // rest of your code
    }
```